# What does 'unit' mean in such a type definition?

Tags: ocaml, ocsigen

```
type waiter =
    { w_wait : unit Lwt.t;
      w_waker: unit Lwt.u option;
      mutable w_did_wait : bool }
```

I don't understand why there are "`unit`" in `w_wait` and `w_waker`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Lwt's doc](http://ocsigen.org/lwt/api/Lwt) the type `'a Lwt.t` is the "*type of threads returning a result of type 'a.*", so your `w_wait` is a cooperative thread returning unit (i.e. having only side effects). Likewise `'a Lwt.u`  is the "*type of thread wakeners*".

I don't understand what you don't understand in Lwt documentation. It seems quite understandable to me.

Comment: I just want to taste ocsigen.  I will have a look at doc later. thanks!